# CircleImageView not showing the image

Tags: android, xml, imageview

Even after setting the source to my circulerView it is not showing any image, but when I use simple ImageView it works fine.
I have cardview and constrainLayout on it and I'm trying to put my CirculerImageView on it.
Also when I set background it shows the image but in square form.
Why my CirculerView is not working?
Should I create a new raw ring shape file?

Please help me.

**my .xml file**

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/constrain_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/driverInfo"
    android:layout_width="335dp"
    android:layout_height="171dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
    map:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/map"
    map:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/map"
    map:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="52dp"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:drawingCacheQuality="high"
            map:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            map:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:srcCompat="@drawable/userimage" />

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="62dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
            android:isIndicator="true"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:stepSize="0.1"
            map:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
            map:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
            android:text="Vaibhav"
            android:textColor="#323643"
            map:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
            map:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/callDriver"
            android:layout_width="111dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="62dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonrect"
            android:text="Call Driver"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            map:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ratingBar"
            map:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    map:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    map:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    map:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    map:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    map:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    map:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/myLocation"
    android:layout_width="335dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edittextlocation"
    android:drawingCacheQuality="high"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="My Location"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:paddingStart="40dp"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:viewportWidth="335"
    android:viewportHeight="48"
    map:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/map"
    map:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/map"
    map:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/destination"
    android:layout_width="335dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="@drawable/destination"
    android:drawingCacheQuality="high"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Destination Please! ?"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:paddingStart="40dp"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    map:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/map"
    map:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/map"
    map:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/myLocation" />


<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    map:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    map:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    map:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="101dp"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#323643"
            android:textSize="18dp" />
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Are You Implemented This Line To Dependency implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0' ?

Comment: How your are loading your image to circleimage view using glide or picasso or any else

Comment: @ManiKandan Yes, I implemented it.

Comment: @SilverskyTechnology Right now I'm only working on XML code, I'm loading image using srcCompat u can see it in XML code.

Comment: You Can also circle image using glide without circleimageview library

Answer (score 2):

Try this code in java file do not need to use external library for make circle image view

```
Glide.with(context)
        .load(url)
        .apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())
        .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace-:

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="52dp"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:drawingCacheQuality="high"
            map:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            map:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:srcCompat="@drawable/userimage" />
```

with-:

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="52dp"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:drawingCacheQuality="high"
            map:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            map:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:src="@drawable/userimage" />


android:src="@drawable/userimage"
```

Comment: using ```tools:srcCompat``` will only show you the image in the layout editor, you normally use ```tools:...``` for when you need to have images or texts etc. for reference while editing but don't actually want it to show up in app during actual runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Try using normal ImageView and change the shape dynamically using the below code.

```
profile = new ImageView(ProfileActivity.this);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.avatar);
Bitmap circularBitmap = ImageConverter.getRoundedCroppedBitmap(bitmap, 100);
profile.setImageBitmap(circularBitmap);
```